# How to iterate rows in StyleFrame?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, styleframe

I want to find colored cells by iterating the rows.

[image]

I know how to iterate columns, but not rows.
In pandas dataframe, it would be

```py
for i in range(0, len(df.index), 1):
    print(df.loc[i, 1])
```

But StyleFrame does not have `loc`. How can I iterate it and check colored cell?

Thanks!

Comment: "I want to iterate rows in StyleFrame, so that I can have only colored cell"  What does this mean? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyleFrame maintainer here... that was a fun one...

The problem here consists of 2 parts:

- The default behavior of Pandas' `read_excel` (which StyleFrame uses) is to skip blank rows. Thankfully it accepts a keyword argument to change this behavior, and StyleFrame's `read_excel` passes every keyword argument it does not know to Pandas. Hence this problem can be fixed pretty easily:

  ```
  StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True, skip_blank_lines=False)
  ```
- The second issue/problematic behavior is that openpyxl sets the background color of cells whose background wasn't changed (or has been set to "automatic" or "no fill", depending on your spreadsheet software) to "000000", which is black.

  This introduced a bug in StyleFrame which, to be honest, I'm not sure how didn't surface until now.

  To fix this issue you can make a small change in StyleFrame's code. Line #111 in styler.py (assuming your are using version 2.0.5 of StyleFrame) should be changed from

  ```
  bg_color = openpyxl_style.fill.fgColor.rgb
  ```

  to

  ```
  bg_color = openpyxl_style.fill.fgColor.rgb if openpyxl_style.fill.patternType is not None else utils.colors.white
  ```

  This change will be included in the next version.

Then, after fixing both issues above, fixing your actual problem becomes relatively easy (although not as easy as I'd have wished it to be):

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, utils

def only_cells_with_colored_background(cell):
    return cell if cell.style.bg_color not in {utils.colors.white, 'FFFFFFFF'} else np.nan

sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True, skip_blank_lines=False)
sf = StyleFrame(sf.applymap(only_cells_with_colored_background).dropna(axis=(0, 1),
                how='all'))
print(sf)
```

Will output

```
   Unnamed: 0
2           a
3           b
4           c
9           a
10          b
11          c
```

I'm planning on implementing a `.style` accessor in a future version, so hopefully the above example will be as simple as

```
sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True, skip_blank_lines=False)
sf = sf.loc[~(sf['Unnamed: 0'].style.bg_color == utils.colors.white)]
```